# Handle different token transfer to contract

Tags: transfer

Any way to handle token transfer to contract with another token?
For example:
first contract - token A
second contract - token B

how to handle transfer token A to contract of token B and make some logic when this transfer send?

example of logic:
after get token B on token A contract we call mint/burn function.

Comment: Using EIP-20 tokens it is possible with some help using approve+transferFrom, with EIP-1155 tokens they can provide a callback for transfers

Comment: its for send tokens, right? but how the second contract will know about it, how can we catch this transfer on him?

Comment: For [EIP-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) tokens you have to implement `ERC1155TokenReceiver` interface. For regular EIP-20 it is not possible directly, you have to use approve+transferFrom. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make two contracts dependent on each other, when we sending the tokens of the first contract to the second, the second contract mints his tokens, and the tokens of the first contract are locked at the address of the second contract and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible using approve + transferFrom. For example something like this should work:

- Code for locking tokens

```
contract B is ERC20 {

    mapping (address => uint256) public locked;

    IERC20 public tokenA;

    function lockTokens(uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == address(tokenA), "Only token A can lock tokens");

        // Lock tokens from A
        tokenA.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        locked[msg.sender] += amount;

        // Mint B tokens
        _mint(msg.sender, amount);         
    }

}
```

- Code for sending tokens from A

```
contract A is ERC20 {

    IERC20 public tokenB;

    function sendToken(uint256 amount) public {
         // Approve tokenB access to A tokens
         approve(address(tokenB), amount);

         // lock A tokens in B
         tokenB.lockTokens(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's if we have 2 contracts inside one file, right? How can we listen this functions from different contract? If two contracts deployed with different files and addresses.

Comment: @Ched I'd recommend to use separate files, one for each contract. For two ERC-20 tokens it is required to deploy separate contract, each having its own address. For ERC-1155 you could deploy a single contract that manages both.

Comment: yes, I need two separate contracts, but how then can I refer to them like this if its in different files(IERC20 public tokenB)?

Comment: @Ched The easiest solution is to add a `init()` function to each contract initialize those fields that can't set in the constructor.